# Searching Chef nodes by age

Tags: chef

I'm trying to put together a tool to track Chef instances that have not converged properly. I can find those nodes easily, but I want to exclude nodes that are still pretty new, and so might still be in the process of bootstrapping. I was originally using `ohai_time` for this, but that wasn't accurate because I'm running Chef as a service, so some nodes would keep failing but keep updating `ohai_time`. Then I found `uptime_seconds`, which seems perfect, but it seems to be handled as a string in range searches, i.e. alphabetically. For example:

```
knife search "uptime_seconds:[0 TO 9]"
```

returns all my instances, whereas:

```
knife search "uptime_seconds:[0 TO 10000]"
```

returns none. Is there any way to handle this correctly using Chef search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. We store all node attributes in a string field as far as Lucene knows so that `TO` is a string range search, not a numeric range.